# Tradução de recompensa

Tags: bug, tradução

Reparei agora que quando se oferece uma recompensa aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

"**até em 15 horas**" não soa muito bem.

Sugestão: "oferece uma recompensa, **que termina em 15 horas**, de...".

Nota: E também não é "nessa pergunta" e sim "nesta pergunta".

Comment: Editei porque tem de ser mudado o sitio onde aparece o termino da recompensa.

Comment: Relacionado: [Tradução a melhorar quando gratificação expira](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1974/3117)

Comment: E também não é "nessa pergunta" e sim "nesta pergunta"

Comment: Jorge, não consigo perceber a diferença :/

Comment: Tem aqui um link, [neste vs nesse](http://duvidas.dicio.com.br/neste-ou-nesse/). Se mesmo assim não perceber vai ao *chat* que eu explico.